# `memo` vs `useMemo` when using `ReactNode` as a prop of another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand the difference between `memo` and `useMemo`. I have an icon component which is passed as a prop to another component. The problem is that even if I `memo` it, the component which accept it as a prop rerender.Using `useMemo` solves the problem but I don't know why `memo` does not work. Below is code:

```
import { Editor } from '@tiptap/react';
import { MenuButton } from '@/components/editor/components/menu-button';
import BoldIcon from '@/components/editor/icons/bold-icon';
import { TooltipContent } from '@/components/editor/components/tooltip-content';
import { _t } from '@/components/editor/utils/localized-strings';
import { memo, useCallback, useContext, useMemo } from 'react';
import { EditorContext } from '@/components/editor/editor';

const MemoMenuButton = memo(MenuButton);
const MemoBoldIcon = memo(BoldIcon);

export const BoldButton = () => {
  const { editor } = useContext(EditorContext);
  const command = useCallback(
    () => editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run(),
    [editor]
  );

  const icon = useMemo(() => {
    return <BoldIcon />;
  }, []);

  const memoIcon = <MemoBoldIcon />;

  return (
    <MemoMenuButton
      id={'bold'}
      icon={memoIcon} // This causes rerender, while icon doesn't, why?
      command={command}
      disabled={!editor.can().toggleBold()}
      active={editor.isActive('bold')}
      // tooltip={{
      //   content: (
      //     <TooltipContent title={_t('commands.bold')} shortcut='Mod-B' />
      //   ),
      // }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const memoIcon = <MemoBoldIcon />;` creates a new element object every time your `BoldButton` renders. This will cause the memoisation in `MemoMenuButton` to detect that its props have changed, rendering `MenuButton` again.

Using `useMemo()` around the `<MemoBoldIcon />` means the element object is memoised between renders of `BoldButton`, passing the same object to `<MenuButton>` every time.

Another, simpler solution to achieve that is to defined the `const memoIcon = <MemoBoldIcon />;` outside of the `BoldButton` funciton declaration, making it a module-scoped constant.

Using `memo(BoldIcon)` does not achieve anything here, that only avoids rerenders of the `BoldIcon` component itself when its props change, however you are not passing any. It does not affect the rendering of the `MenuButton` at all.

---

Btw I'd recommend to get rid of the `memo()` and `useCallback` calls altogether, and wrap the entire code of the `BoldButton` in a single `useMemo` that has the `editor` as its dependency:

```
export function BoldButton() {
  const { editor } = useContext(EditorContext);
  return useMemo(() => (
    <MenuButton
      id={'bold'}
      icon={<BoldIcon />}
      command={() => editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()}
      disabled={!editor.can().toggleBold()}
      active={editor.isActive('bold')}
      tooltip={{
        content: (
          <TooltipContent title={_t('commands.bold')} shortcut='Mod-B' />
        ),
      }}
    />
  ), [editor]);
};
```

If you need to prevent the icon and the tooltip from re-rendering even when the `editor` changes (I doubt it matters), extract them into separate constants:

```
const icon = <BoldIcon />;
const tooltip = {
  content: (
    <TooltipContent title={_t('commands.bold')} shortcut='Mod-B' />
  ),
};
export function BoldButton() {
  const { editor } = useContext(EditorContext);
  return useMemo(() => (
    <MenuButton
      id={'bold'}
      icon={icon}
      command={() => editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()}
      disabled={!editor.can().toggleBold()}
      active={editor.isActive('bold')}
      tooltip={tooltip}
    />
  ), [editor]);
};
```

Comment: I can't wrap `BoldButton` into `useMemo` as `editor` passed as a dependency never causes the rerender of this component. That's why I used `useCallback` for `command` prop and it seems that now I have to use `useMemo` on not memoized `BoldIcon`. But I still don't get why `  const memoIcon = <MemoBoldIcon />;` is different for every rerender of `BoldButton` - its memoized and props never changes because there is no props in the end.  expected it to work this way. I can use `useMemo` but it adds some extra lines of code

Comment: "*why `const memoIcon = <MemoBoldIcon />;` is different for every rerender of BoldButton, it's memoized*" - no it's not a memoized value. A `MemoBoldIcon` will **memoize its props** when it is being rendered. But the value `memoIcon` itself, a react element object, is new every time the `const memoIcon = …` is executed.

Comment: "*I can't wrap [the code of] `BoldButton` into `useMemo`*" - yes you can. If `editor` never changes, the entire `BoldButton` never needs to rerender. It's a feature, not a bug :-) Unless `editor` is mutable, of course, but then you have bigger problems, like the `EditorContext` not working either.

Comment: Great thank you! Indeed I moved `icon` completely outside the component as you suggested and thanks to this there is no need to use `useMemo` on it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ""I can't wrap [the code of] BoldButton into useMemo" - yes you can. If editor never changes, the entire BoldButton never needs to rerender. It's a feature, not a bug." - here the problem is that I use `editor.isActive('bold')` as `active` prop to determine whether button should be highlighted or not. It will change only if I click from not-bold to bold text and vice versa. If I wrap the entire `BoldButton` into `useMemo` then the button never changes and hence its never highlighted because `editor` is all the time the same and does not cause rerender.

Comment: Here is source code behind `editor` https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/develop/packages/react/src/useEditor.ts

Comment: @Ugus Oh well, that code has some problems… It could be improved to better follow the React guidelines (e.g. using cleanup functions instead of refs), but fundamentally it has the problem of trying to force a stateful editor instance into the React pattern, which is doomed to fail. `forceUpdate` is a clear sign of that… Your `useMemo` (and your `EditorContext` would need to depend on the invisible `useForceUpdate` number value, not on the `editor`. Or they just need to re-render completely every single time.

Comment: In general a component that uses `useEditor` is going to be rerender every single time and that's intentional. My problem was that if I have 20 buttons, then on every keystroke, all of them are being rerender which causes some performence issues. That'w why I `memo` `MenuButton`. For now it must be sufficient. Thank you